# How to make a push button toy always on?

Tags: arduino

I'm modifying toys I've found at thrift stores. I want to be able to flip the on switch and have the toy move until I turn it off. Unfortunately 90% of these toys only work when you turn them on and then press a button to see them dance or go through various motions. I've tried connecting the two wires that go into the button but it only plays through the motion once and then stops.

My idea right now is to attach the wires to a timer so they are activated every 60 seconds or so. Does anyone know how to make a timer like that? Arduino could work but I'd rather do something easier and cheaper.

I attached images of the button that activates the toy. Im hoping to find something that I can just connect to those wires as most of these toys use the same button.

Thank you so much for any help!

ButtonImage1[image]

ButtonImage2[image]

Comment: Sounds like a fun project.. don't really see an objective programming-related question though! (After deciding on *using* an Ardunio unit, as an example, there might be an actual coding questions - like how to ensure the timer is going off every blah blah seconds or following a pattern or reacting to input etc.)

Comment: Of there's gonna be more than a few EE majors who are gonna start with "All you need is a capacitor, resistor, and.." :D

Comment: [Digispark](https://www.banggood.com/Digispark-Kickstarter-Micro-USB-Development-Board-For-ATTINY85-Arduino-p-1038088.html) is a cheap/small form factor Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 555 timer. Several tutorials are available online to vary the frequency of "ticking" of the clock.